# How to stop the audio when open new JFrame

Tags: java, loops, audio

I doing a security warning if user enter wrong password more than 5 time, then it will pop out a frame that asking user to unlock and the frame also will keep on looping the warning sound. After user unlock it, it will jump back to login frame. My problem is after I unlock it, the system jump back to login frame but the sound is still running. Why?

This is my button code jump back to login frame

```
Staff s = new Staff();
       String id = m_id.getText();
       String pass = m_pass.getText();
        String position = "Manager";
        try{
            String sql = "Select * from Staff Where Position='"+position+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                String add = rs.getString("Staff_ID");
               s.setStaff_ID(add);

                String add2 = rs.getString("Password");
                s.setPassword(add2);

            }

            if((s.getStaff_ID().equals(id)) && (s.getPassword().equals(pass))){
                    warning(clip);
                dispose();
                new login().setVisible(true);

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
        }
```

and I use this to loop sound

```
private void warning(){
        try {

         URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sound/aleart.wav");
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

                        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My GUI name is WarningLogin and I call the `warning()` here.

```
public WarningLogin() {
              initComponents();
                warning();
}
```

Comment: Did you try stopping or closing clip?

Comment: I try before, but maybe I put at wrong place?? Where should I put?

Answer (score 0):

First `clip` needs to be a instance field of you class...

```
public class ... {

   private Clip clip;
```

Then when you create it, you need to reference this value...

```
//Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
```

Now, I'd probably using a `WindowListener` and when the `windowClosing` event is raised, try calling `clip.stop()` and because I'm pedantic, `clip.close()`

Comment: thanks, it works. and then I type clip.stop(); in the method I open back the Login frame and the audio stop...Thank you once again

Comment: It's nice to know it worked...seen as I've actually never used the `AudioSystem` :P